# shooting tank with openGL cpp

Tags: c++, opengl, scale

I'm trying to make a shooting tank in OpenGL on C++.

I've drawn the tank and he moves on sin shaped ground, and I want to keep the end of the cannon in variables named `currX`, `currY`. My display function is:

```
void display()
{
    double dx, dy, beta;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clean frame buffer
//  DrawSky();
    DrawGround(); // draws a y = 0.075 * sin(x * 10) shaped ground
    glPushMatrix();

    // rotation of 2*PI equals 2*PI*Radius of Wheel
    // in our case the wheel is rotated each time by angle (in degrees)
    dx = direction * 2 * PI * 0.03 * (angle / 360);
    dy = 0.075 * sin(dx * 10);
    beta = atan(0.075 * 10 * cos(dx * 10)); // derrivative 

    beta *= 180 / PI; // transforms beta to degrees


    glTranslated(dx, dy, 0);
    if (direction == 1)
    {
        glRotated(180, 0, 1, 0);
        beta = -beta;
    }
    glScaled(0.3, 0.3, 1);
    glRotated(beta, 0, 0, 1);
    DrawTank();
    glPopMatrix();
//....
}
```

Now the problem is if I know that the tank cannon end was `P = (-0.285,0.4175)` before it was scaled and translated what will be the x,y of the cannon end at the end?

I've tried to multiply P by 0.3 which is the scaling factor in both x,y axis and its close to the end but not exactly there. What should I do?
should I calculate the currX,currY in the DrawTank or in the display?

in the image below the white point should be located at the end of the cannon.

[image: current result]

Comment: Yes, you will need to redo the calculations yourself. This is one of the many reasons why people recommend against OpenGL 1.x.

Comment: Why do you repeat the question? [shooting tank with openGL cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218426/shooting-tank-with-opengl-cpp/73218502#73218502). Repeating questions to attract attention is not welcome. It is also not intended to delete a question that has an answer just because you don't like the answer. Giving an answer is an effort and you are depriving the person who answered the question of the opportunity to get "upvotes".

Comment: Agree with Botje: maybe OpenGL 1 is okay for learning basic rendering but as soon as you go beyond that - it's not so simple. If you were using modern OpenGL and GLM, you'd already have the translation and rotation matrix in a variable, and you could just write `cannonPoint * cannonMatrix`

Comment: Rabbid I understood that my question was not focusing on the problem that Ive just found so I asked more specific question now.

Comment: You have to edit the original question, not deleted it and not ask a new one.